# Can't copy files on windows

Tags: network-share, windows-10

I've a client, for which I've instantiated a shared folder on Windows 10, I showed him how to manage permissions etc.. The problem is that I'm going to make hardware changes, and I want to copy the data to another driver. When I try to copy some files I get you this error:

```
"You need permissions from admin to make changes to ****" - or something similar
```

The problem is that I'm admin. The first thing I've tried is taking ownership of the files, this didn't work. The second thing I tried is running file explorer as administrator, this didn't work also. The admin account has all permissions allowed and none denied. Any ideas what may be wrong?
**Edit**
 here is what I get from the command line:
1. Navigate to the share

```
E:
```

after that I'm using "cd" to get to the directory containing the file, them

```
E:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3>copy "FileName.max" "F:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\FileName.max"
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

I'm running cmd as administartor
Note that I've changed the names of the directories and the file name for privacy reasons.

Comment: share permissions and file/folder permissions are not the same thing. Make sure the permissions are allowed for both things. Also the way to access the share matters also when involving permissions. Are you using the \\hostname\c$\folder method, or the \\sharename method?

Comment: I'm using the PC on which the shared folder lives. So I can access it with letter only like A:/ for example. The permissions on the share for my user are again allow to all and deny to none

Comment: Could you try from the command line and afterward, then put the commands and responses from the command prompt into your question above? It might provide enough detail to understand how we could reproduce the issue, or help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I've edited the answer, and posted the data there.

Comment: Do administrators have perms on the `destination` path? Are there any active processes that could have a lock on `"Filename.max"`? You can use `HANDLE.EXE` to look for file locks https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx

Comment: The admin account also has full permission on the destination path and Handle64.exe doesn't find any handles associated with the file.

Comment: So you took ownership and then granted explicit NTFS permissions for at least READ access to the top level folder and confirmed it was inherited down the path? This sounds like an issue with the ACL for the NFTS objects and taking ownership and then setting READ access should allow you to copy the data files elsewhere... This shouldn't be hard to get resolved.

Comment: After a I had taking ownership of the file(although, I was already the owner), and set the checked and unchecked the read access, all other permissions disappeared, I mean only my user was left in the listing for permissions, everyone else was remove. However I was able to copy the file this time. Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) tool from SysInternals Suite, while you trying to copy this file. This should give you hint what permissions are required to copy this file.

Comment: Procmon, returned a lot of information. the first thing that semes wrong is that the operation is "createFile", when I'm trying to copy file. Is this OK?
Also here is the description:
Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a

However at the moment this is encrypted for me(I don't understand the information which is given to me)

Comment: This is very low level tool. There should be createFile, queryOpen, closeFile etc. 

I assume that you filtered out all records not related with your source/destination file(s).

When I copied file, procmon gave me almost 150 events. 

First of all you should create filter (Ctrl+L): Path > contain > %YourFileName% > Include

One of the columns in main window of procmon is Result. Check events where Result column is not SUCCESS.

Comment: That was exactly what I've done. I've posted the data from such column.

Comment: The information is: OS trying to perform action "CreateFile" and nedds following access attributes: Read Attributes, Synchronize. When you edit Advanced Permissions for file, you should check whether Read Attributes and Synchronize are checked or not.